# Delete all records older than 1 month Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have 6 months worth of data in my mysql database.
I want to delete all the records that are older than 1 month.
So i only want the current month of records left.

**I have tried :**

```
DB::table('applicants')->whereRaw('AppDate < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to manual, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#deletes this could be work for you

```
DB::table('applicants')->where('AppDate', '<', 'NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY')->delete();
```

1st - select from **table()**, then **where()** condition then **delete()**

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.